# What are all the automatic parameters of android's camera2 API

Tags: android, api, camera, camera2

I'm developing a camera app using the Android camera2 API, And I need the camera to have always the same configuration, like focus, white balance, exposure, etc.

I already disabled AF, AE and AWB, but it still seems to automatically set the white balance. I was wondering if is there some other automatic configuration I should disable.

I didn't find anything like it on Google.

Comment: For AWB, did you use a mode like SHADE or TWILIGHT or did you set it to  CONTROL_AWB_MODE_OFF?

Comment: I did set it to CONTROL_AWB_MODE_OFF, all I did so far actually was to set CONTROL_AF_MODE_OFF, CONTROL_AE_MODE_OFF and CONTROL_AWB_MODE_OFF, is it necessary that I set an value to focus, exposure and white balance?

Comment: I wouldn't have thought so. I thought I had something for this but it looks like I don't.

Comment: :/ thanks for trying anyway 

Answer (score 0):

i just ran into the same issue... In my case it turned out, that there was a function in the template i was using, which reset the control mode to automatic.

```
protected void updatePreview() {
    if(null == cameraDevice) {
        Log.e(TAG, "updatePreview error, return");
    }
    captureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_MODE_AUTO);
    try {
        cameraCaptureSessions.setRepeatingRequest(captureRequestBuilder.build(), null, mBackgroundHandler);
    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```